# for loop is not working in protractor

Tags: javascript, for-loop, protractor

I have used the below for loop to click on the icon in 5th index of ***td***, if the 2nd index of ***td*** contains text (which is passed as external parameter) as expected.

I'm getting the row elements as ***tenantRowElements*** and written the following code.

The outcome is reached i.e, the expected button is clicked but still am facing the below error and it is not moving into next method.

[image: Error Image]

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
>    error.

```
this.clickEditOfTenant=function(userobj) {
    console.log("Edit of tenant is clicked");
    basePage.waitForElement(this.tenantRowElements, 5000);

    this.tenantRowElements.then(function (tenants) {
        console.log("element length : " + tenants.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < tenants.length; i++) {
            tenants[i].$$('td').then(function (tds) {
                tds[1].getText().then(function (text) {
                    return text;
                }).then(function (name) {
                    console.log("tenant name : " + name + "; given name :" + userobj.tname);
                    if (name === userobj.tname) {
                        tds[5].click();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }).then(function () {
        if(basePage.isVisible(updateTenant.tenantNameTxtBox))
        {console.log("Edit button is clicked");}

    });
};
```

Comment: Is possible more than one row can be found which tenant name is same as given `userobj.tname`?

Comment: yes. more than one row can be found

Answer (score 1):

i have edited as below, and now its working

```
this.clickEditOfTenant = function(userobj) {
    console.log("call clickEditOfTenant()");
    basePage.waitForElement(this.tenantRowElements, 10000);

    //browser.sleep(15000);
    this.tenantRowElements.filter(function (tr) {
        return tr.all(by.css('td')).get(1).getText().then(function (name) {
            return name === userobj.tname;
        });
    }).then(function (eles) {
        eles[0].$$('td').then(function (btn) {
            //console.log(text);
            btn[5].click();
        }).then(function () {
            browser.sleep(5000);
            if (basePage.isVisible(updateTenant.tenantNameTxtBox)) {
                console.log("Edit button is clicked");
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Yong. Anyway i found solution finally

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `basePage.waitForElement(this.tenantRowElements, 5000);` is not sufficient to wait the page complete load. So you met the issue at the **first** iteration of loop,

Add `browser.sleep(15000)` after `basePage.waitForElement(this.tenantRowElements, 5000);` for debug purpose.

And you can use `filter()` to make your code briefness:

```
this.clickEditOfTenant = function(userobj) {

  console.log("call clickEditOfTenant()");

  // basePage.waitForElement(this.tenantRowElements, 5000);

  browser.sleep(15000)

  this.tenantRowElements.filter(function(tr) {
    return tr.all(by.css('td')).get(1).getText().then(function(name) {
      return name === userobj.tname;
    });
  })
  .then(function(eles) {
    if(eles.length > 0) {
      eles[0].click();
    }
  })
  .then(function () {
    if(basePage.isVisible(updateTenant.tenantNameTxtBox)) {
      console.log("Edit button is clicked");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks yong. But still, i need to get the 5th td from eles where i can get a btn to click. i hope eles will return selected rows.